# Monogame apply tint to only some parts of sprite

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame, spritesheet

Each player is a different colour (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow) and I want a small part of each piece of armour to be tinted to the player colour.  Is this possible without using a second armour sprite that overlays?

I'm hoping for something along the lines of reserving a certain portion of colours (say various shades of magenta) to convert back to a player colour while drawing.

Comment: or https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-a-good-method-for-coloring-textures-based-on-a-palette-in-xna/11307#11307